# Using Dapper to populate a List of Items

Tags: c#, angularjs, dapper

I have a single page application that contains the following classes:

```
public class Item{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public List<ItemRate> Rates {get;set;}
}

public class ItemRate{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ItemId {get;set}
    public float straightTime {get;set;}
    public float overTime {get;set;}
}
```

I have a service that gets the items with this method:

```
public List<Item> GetItems(string companyId)
{
    return _itemRepository.GetItems(companyId);
}
```

`_itemRepository.GetItems` simply calls a stored procedure that returns a table with columns `Id` and `Description`.

I would like to be able to populate the `List<ItemRate>` along with the related `Item`. Otherwise, I have to call a method to get the `ItemRate` for each `Item`. When I was displaying the data in a form for one `Item` at a time, that was fine. Now, I have a requirement to display a table (`ng-repeat`) that shows the `ItemRates` on the same row. I may have 100+ `Items` and would like to avoid manually building the `ItemRate` list for each and every `Item`. *(I will never have more than 5 `ItemRate` records per `Item` so that won't be an issue).*

If I were to manually build the JSON string, it would look like this:

```
[{
  "Id": "5",
  "Description": "First One",
  "Rates": [{
      "Id": "15",
      "ItemId": "5",
      "straightTime": "10",
      "overTime": "0"
   }, {
      "Id": "27",
      "ItemId": "5",
      "straightTime": "7",
      "overTime": "5"
   }]
}, {
  "Id": "9",
  "Description": "Second One",
  "Rates": [{
      "Id": "7",
      "ItemId": "9",
      "straightTime": "8",
      "overTime": "1"
   }]
}]
```

Is this possible? What is the most efficient method? Do I need to do this join in the SQL statement? Can I get all `ItemRates` and then easily connect them to the correct `Item` in C#?

I know I could use SQL to build the JSON string with the appropriate content, but SQL is not the place to do that, and I skip the benefit of using the proper tools for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I changed the classes so I can use linq contains methods for quick test.

```
public class ItemRate : IEquatable<ItemRate>
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int ItemId { get; set; }
            public float straightTime { get; set; }
            public float overTime { get; set; }

            public bool Equals(ItemRate obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                    return false;

                if (obj.Id == this.Id)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
        }



public class Item : IEquatable<Item>
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public List<ItemRate> Rates { get; set; }

            public bool Equals(Item obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                    return false;

                if (obj.Id == this.Id)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Now I created a test function to load the items and the rates at the same time.  Your stored proc would be returning, Id, Desc, RateId, StraightTime, OverTime now. I.E.

```
SELECT i.Id, i.Desc, r.Id AS RateId, r.StraightTime, r.OverTime 
FROM Items i 
INNER JOIN Rates 
on r.ItemId = i.Id
```

Now lets load the whole shebang in one shot.

```
        public List<Item> LoadItems()
        {
            //Lets make some fake data
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Desc", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RateId", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StraightTime", typeof(float)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OverTime", typeof(float)));

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                dr["Id"] = (x % 5);
                dr["Desc"] = String.Format("Desc{0}", (x % 5));
                dr["RateId"] = (x % 20);
                dr["StraightTime"] = (x * 5.5f);
                dr["OverTime"] = (x * 1.5f);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }


            //Loading the list
            List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Item i = new Item();
                i.Id = (int)dr["Id"];
                i.Description = dr["Desc"].ToString();
                i.Rates = new List<ItemRate>();

                if (!itemList.Contains(i))
                {
                    itemList.Add(i);
                }

                ItemRate r = new ItemRate();
                r.Id = (int)dr["RateId"];
                r.ItemId = (int)dr["Id"];
                r.overTime = (float)dr["StraightTime"];
                r.straightTime = (float)dr["OverTime"];

                var f = itemList.Where(o => o.Id == r.ItemId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (f != null)
                {
                    if (!f.Rates.Contains(r))
                    {
                        f.Rates.Add(r);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way for `ms-odata` to do it automatically rather than manually creating the string.